# Sometimes Jquery.width() and .height() working wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to loop all imgs(hundreds of images) and I want to get width of images.
But sometimes width and height return 0 or something wrong.

**Code**

```
$('img').each(function(){
    var image = jQuery(this);
    $(this).load(function(){
        var width = img.width(), height=img.height();

        //do something with width and height
    })

})
```

I tried with `jquery.load` and window.load function but it is also same.
Anybody who knows solution

Comment: What if images are already loaded ?

Comment: why are you using ajax,where did you defined the img variable?

Comment: Try `window.load` method for this. It will fire after all your images are loaded.

Comment: `img.width()` ? `img` will be __undefined__

Comment: @Alorika I also used window.load but it's same.

Comment: do you have ajaxed images ?

Comment: @RayonDabre plz see code again. and if you want more plz look at jsfiddle.net.  http://jsfiddle.net/jengge/xhjvvhu2/1/  and live blog. https://tag-test-super-star.c9users.io/

Comment: Nothing happens on the fiddle...Kindly correct the errors...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `jQuery` [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) when events are binding in a loop, because events will bind every time the loop executes.

```
$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).one('load', function(){
         console.log('W:'+this.width+', H:'+this.height)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(function(){
$('img').each(function(i,v){
  console.log($(v).width(),$(v).height());
});
});
```

or:

```
  $(function(){
    $('img').each(function(i,v){
      console.log($(v).css('width'),$(v).css('height'));
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$('img').each(function() {
  _this = $(this);
  _this.load(function() {
    var width = _this.width(),
      height = _this.height();
    console.log(width);
    console.log(height);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'>
<img src='https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'>
<img src='https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'>
<img src='https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'>
```

Comment: I've also used that. but sometimes work and sometimes not work. live blog is https://tag-test-super-star.c9users.io/ and jsfiddle.net. jsfiddle.net/jengge/xhjvvhu2/1

Comment: You will have to provide those scenarios..

Answer (score 1):

```
try this   

 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(function(){
     $("img").each(function(){
       alert($(this).attr("width"));
       alert($(this).attr("height"));
    });
    })
    </script>
    <body>

    <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
    <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="43" height="42">
    <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="44" height="42">
    <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="45" height="42">


    </body>
    </html>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
 $("img").each(function(){
   alert("height:"+$(this).css("height") +"\t width:"+$(this).css("width"));

});
})
</script>
<body>

<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" style="width:42px;height:48px">
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" style="width:45px;height:100px">
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" style="width:46px;height:46px">
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" style="width:48px;height:40px">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until images are loaded.

Comment: Why do you open a bounty for this question???